# Show that $A \subset B \implies A \cap B = A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to show that:

$$A \subset B \implies A \cap B = A$$

So far I got:

$$A \subset B$$
$$A \cap B \subset A$$
$$A \cap B \subset B$$
$$A \cap B \subset A \subset B$$

Comment: Use the axiom of extension, i.e show that any element in A is in A intersected with B and vice versa.

Comment: Yes @Clarinetist it is a duplicate (part of), but I leave it here because I think the accepted answer is more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$A\cap B \subset A$.

On the other hand if $x\in A $ then $x\in B$ (because $A\subset B$).

Since $x\in A$ and $x\in B$ we have $x\in A\cap B$, so $A\subset A\cap B$

Answer (score 3):

Clearly  $A\cap B \subseteq A.$
Conversely $A \subseteq A\cap B$ since:
 Let $x\in A$ then, by assumption, $x\in B$. So $x\in A\cap B$.

Answer (score 2):

Doing little diagrams can help to see what happens :

[image: set]

From this, you see that :

- $x \in A \cap B$ implies $x \in A$ and $x \in B$, so in particular $x\in A$
- $x \in A$ implies $x \in A \cap B$, since every element of $A$ is also an element of $B$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $A\subseteq B$

Let $x\in A\cap B$

Then $x\in A$ and $x\in B$

In particular this implies that $x\in A$ which shows $A\cap B\subseteq A$

Now, suppose instead that $y\in A$

Since $A\subseteq B$ that implies that $y\in B$ also

As a result, $y\in A$ and $y\in B$

This implies $y\in A\cap B$ which shows $A\subseteq A\cap B$

Since $A\cap B\subseteq A$ and $A\subseteq A\cap B$, it must be that $A\cap B=A$

---

Alternatively, with $A\subseteq B$ you can write $B=A\cup (B\setminus A)$

You have then $A\cap B = A\cap (A\cup (B\setminus A))=(A\cap A)\cup (A\cap B\cap A^c)=A\cup \emptyset = A$

Answer (score 0):

Equality of sets is equivalent to the conjunction of two inclusions. You have established the inclusion $A\cap B\subset A$ and you need to establish the other direction of the inequality, namely

$$A\subset A\cap B$$

For this, observe that $X\subset Y\wedge X\subset Z\implies X\subset Y\cap Z.$ Alternatively use the definition of the intersection and prove that any element in $A$ is also in $A\cap B.$

Answer (score 0):

A definition of $A\subseteq B$ is $x\in A \implies x\in B$.

A definition of $A\cap B$ is $A\cap B=\{x:x\in A \land x\in B\}$.

Therefore if we have $A\subseteq B$, we have $A\cap B=\{x:x\in A \}=A$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that
$$\begin{aligned}
A\cap B\neq A\quad&\Longleftrightarrow\quad A\cap B\not\subset A\quad\text{or}\quad A\not\subset A\cap B\\
&\Longleftrightarrow\quad A\not\subset A\cap B\\
&\Longleftrightarrow\quad A\not\subset A\quad\text{or}\quad A\not\subset B\\
&\Longleftrightarrow \quad A\not\subset B
\end{aligned}$$
and thus
$$A\subset B\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad A\cap B=A$$